# What happens when you use the individual characters in 姓氏 and 名字?

Tags: mandarin, simplified-characters

姓氏 refers to surname, and 名字 refers to personal name.

But I’ve heard people using the separate characters to talk about surnames and personal names.

For example:

> 我的中文老师姓姚
>
> 林氏集团 (Lin’s Corporation, like one of those companies named after their founder)
>
> 她名叫小丽
>
> 字: I’m not too sure about this one, but I know 李白’s 字 is 太白

What is the difference between all these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my answer to this question [What does this symbol mean?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23976/what-does-this-symbol-mean/23978#23978) I explained 姓氏 It may be a good reference to your question

From my answer to this question [Why is there such a difference between "first name" and "last name"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/31395/why-is-there-such-a-difference-between-first-name-and-last-name) I explained 姓 and 名字

> In the past, most people in high society would have a 姓(family name), a 名 (given name) and a 字 ([Courtesy name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtesy_name))

Example of using individual characters in 姓氏 and 名字:

- 他姓曹 = his last name is 曹
- 曹氏一族 = the clan of 曹 family
- 他姓曹，名操，字孟德 = his last name is 曹, first name is 操 and his courtesy name is 孟德