# Why is 名字 used with 叫, but 姓 isn't?

Tags: grammar

Examples:

> 我姓李。
>
> 我名字叫张。

Why not 我姓叫李?

Comment: Not a Chinese answer, but you actually get the same idea in English. “I am called John”, “My surname is Smith”. Not, “My surname is called Smith”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my answer to this question: [Why is there such a difference between "first name" and "last name"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/31395/why-is-there-such-a-difference-between-first-name-and-last-name)

> "你姓什么?" - the noun '姓' here is acting like a verb (is family-named)
>
> .......
>
> We only use 名字 as a noun, therefore we need a verb '是'(is) or '叫'(called) when asking what is someone's name. e.g. "你的名字是什么" or "你的名字叫什么"

When you say "我姓李", the word "姓" is acting like a verb

"我[姓]李" = "I [am family-named] Lee"

When you say 我名字叫李小龍, 名字 cannot only be treated as a noun, not a verb, therefore you need to add a verb '是'(is) or '叫'(called)

From another related post: [What happens when you use the individual characters in 姓氏 and 名字?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36692/what-happens-when-you-use-the-individual-characters-in-%e5%a7%93%e6%b0%8f-and-%e5%90%8d%e5%ad%97)*

> For example:
>
> 曹操 Cao Cao
>
> 姓:曹 (is last-named: Cao)
>
> 名:操 (is first-named:Cao)
>
> 字:孟德 (is courtesy-named: Meng Deo)

When you use just 名 instead of 名字 , you can omit "叫" and treat "名" like a verb, and say  "我姓曹名操"  instead of "我姓曹, 名字叫操"

The reason for omitting "叫" is: "名" (is first-named) already acting as a verb, the verb "叫" (is called) is redundant

Comment: If you wish to formally introduce yourself, it's -- 我名字和姓氏是。。。。。（姓氏 means family / clan name)

Comment: So, can I say 我名操?

Comment: No, 姓曹名操 have to be together.